# Unable to perform HTTPPost request from Android App to ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api

HTTPResponse returning **"org.apache.http.conn.eofsensorinputstream@b3eb3b78**

- I am using POST method to a JSON object to a WebAPI service.

  ```
      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
      String restTokenUrl = "http://XXXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/Tokens/createToken";
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(restTokenUrl);
  ```
- JSONobject which is appending to my WebAPI Service

  ```
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
  json.put("student_id", "2");
  json.put("dept_Id", "1");
  json.put("issue", "Unable to register");
  json.put("closingTime", "2015-11-16T00:05:22.613");
  HttpEntity e = new StringEntity(json.toString());
  httpPost.setEntity(e);
  httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
  InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
  String result = inputStream.toString();
  Log.d(result);
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are getting a valid response, but `inputStream.toString()` doesn't do what you think it does.

**It isn't reading the stream as a string**, but rather just using the default implementation and returning the class's name and the instance's address in memory.

You can use Apache's [EntityUtils](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29) to actually read the contents as a string:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
Log.d(result);
```